# Vibe.d REST Interface serve image

Tags: rest, d, vibed

Sending a bunch of binary back to the user like an image:

```
interface API
{
  @path("/data/image")
  @contentType("image/png")
  ubyte[] getImagePreview(string foo);
}
```

The function is returning a `Json` array with the values of the `ubyte[]`

Here are the list of attributes I can use:

```
adjustMethodStyle
bodyParam
contentType
extractHTTPMethodAndName
headerParam
method
noRoute
path
queryParam
rootPathFromName
```

Source: [Vibe.d site](http://vibed.org/api/vibe.web.common/)

The only attribute that can do the job is `contentType` and it's said there that it only works with `ubyte[]` functions, and that's what I used.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can try hunt framework so easy use:

```
    @Action
    Response image(string imageName)
    {
        return new FileResponse("/data/image/" ~ imageName);
    }
```

More read wiki:
https://github.com/huntlabs/hunt-framework/wiki/FileResponse